# Does adding prefixes to SI units make them no longer SI units?

Tags: notation, units

Our chemistry professor said that "mg for mass, g/m<sup>3</sup> for density, ms for time are all SI units".

I want to make sure now, even if we added a prefix to the unit, will it still be an SI unit?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units).

Answer (score 13):

Yes, when prefixes are used with coherent SI units, the resulting units are still SI units; however, they are no longer coherent.

> The metre per second, symbol m/s, is the coherent SI unit of speed. The kilometre per second, km/s, the centimetre per second, cm/s, and the millimetre per second, mm/s, are also SI units, but they are not coherent SI units.

BIPM: [The International System of Units (SI)](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/)

Comment: Worth mentioning the exception to the rule: `kg` is the base unit of mass, not grams.  See also https://www.unc.edu/~rowlett/units/cgsmks.html: the CGS system (centimeter, gram, second) used to be the base units (with force in dynes for example), but now almost everyone uses MKS (with force in Newtons).

Comment: The main advantage of Metric/SI is that everything makes sense and is so easy to work with. Which is why it infuriates me that the base unit of mass is `kg`. WHY? Why would you ruin an otherwise perfect system? Like, in a system all about logical unit choices, you go and do that. Sigh.